# Running figure numbering

Tags: floats, numbering, captions, koma-script, punctuation

I want to use running figure numbering so I used a trick form this website https://texfaq.org/FAQ-running-nos.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
...
\begin{appendix}
\chapter{Algorithms}
...
\end{appendix}
```

It kind-of-works: The figures numbers look like this e.g. `Figure 2.:`, `Figure 3.:` ... How can i get rid of the `.`?

Is there a fix or a better solution?

Comment: Does the `.` form part of the number? When you use `\ref{<some figure>}`, do you get a number *plus* `.`?

Comment: No just the number.

Comment: Since this is not the output I receive, could you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that duplicates your problem? There may be other definitions in your preamble that causes this behaviour since it is not the expected output given your setup. Without an MWE it will be difficult to correct it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

As Werner has suggested, it is _always_ best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages. Personally, I have often solved my own problems in the process of reducing the amount of code actually required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advince. Due to a little bit ouf time pressure I couldn't provide a MWE before my deadline. Sorry for that! But now lockstep solved the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a guess: Do you use the [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) class `scrbook` or `scrreprt` *and* does your document exhibit an appendix chapter? If so, a closing dot will automatically be added to the numbering of sectioning titles and float captions. To remove the dot, add `\KOMAoptions{numbers=noendperiod}` to your preamble.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

% \KOMAoptions{numbers=noendperiod}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\appendix

\chapter{bar}

\end{document}
```